# A Open source C library which provides sending email function?

Tags: c, email, solaris

all:

Is there any good open source C library which provides sending email function? I don't want use mailx command in Solaris.
    Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry I bet he uses Solaris

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: Solaris.

Comment: @Aniket Are you a mind reader or something?

Comment: @squiguy lol kind of :-P

Comment: @Aniket: Are there any advices? Thanks!

Comment: Why not read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol and then roll your own? It's not so complicated.

Comment: There are a number of libraries that handle SMTP.  Google will find several very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just searched on google and found these few link..hope this will help.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwsmtp/?source=dlp

http://www.stafford.uklinux.net/libesmtp/download.html